# Reduce repeat code with declare lot of variable with the same data type

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have declared the variable as below:

```
$Capacity = array();
$ProRender = array();
$Polyalence = array();
$CapacityMener = array();
$RespectDelais = array();
```

I do not want to write code  `array()` again and again.Have any method that can fix this?Anyone help me please,Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One posibility:

```
$Capacity = $ProRender = $Polyalence = $CapacityMener = $RespectDelais = array();
```

Or if you have PHP 5.4, there is the short array syntax:

```
$Capacity = [];
$ProRender = [];
...
```